# Showing a surjection of a cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let A and B be sets and let $f : A → B$ be a bijection.
Let g be the function$ g : A × A → B × B$, given by $$g(a_1, a_2) = (f(a_1), f(a_2))$$ for all
$(a_1, a_2) ∈ A × A.$
Show that g is a bijection. 
g is a well defined function.

So my thought was ill just pick a random element of the domain $(a_1',a_2')$ and put it in the function and say well $f(a_2')$ and $f(a_2')$ should both be uniquely assigned and should be elements of the co-domain since f is a bijection.

Is this right? Or would i have to go and prove it it both bijective and surjective? 
My problem with doing the latter is that when it comes to trying to mess around with the rule of the function g all i can say is well f is surjective so... or f is bijective so...

Thanks for an help

Comment: That is right from 10000ft, but the devil may still be in detail. Could you post the full attempt at the proof (possibly with proof-verification tag) so that we can have a look?

Comment: Hi yeah thats the problem i literally said that, but just with symbols

Comment: To prove $g$ is bijective, you need to show that $g$ is *injective* and surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is right. So show that for any pair $(a,a')$ there is exactly one image and that for any pair $(b,b')$ there is exactly one preimage.

Comment: Alright cool, is it enough just to say well f is a bijection so it must be f(a1) must be uniquely assigned since it dosent give me a rule for the function f?

Comment: @user512254 What do you call "uniquely assigned"?

Answer (score 1):

To establish that $g$ is a bijection, we need to show injectivity and surjectivity.

For injectivity, suppose $g(a_1, a_2)=g(a_1^\prime, a_2^\prime)$. By definition of $g$, this means that we have
$$(f(a_1), f(a_2))=(f(a_1^\prime), f(a_2^\prime))$$ as elements of the cartesian product $B\times B$, which means that $f(a_1)=f(a_1^\prime)$ and $f(a_2)=f(a_2^\prime)$. Now, since $f$ itself is bijective, it is in particular injective so the implications
$$f(a_1)=f(a_1^\prime) \implies a_1=a_1^\prime$$
and
$$f(a_2)=f(a_2^\prime) \implies a_2=a_2^\prime$$
hold. These together yield $(a_1, a_2)=(a_1^\prime, a_2^\prime)$ so $g$ is injective.

For surjectivity, consider some $(b_1, b_2) \in B\times B$. Then, by surjectivity of $f$, there exist $a_1 \in A$ and $a_2 \in A$ such that $f(a_1)=b_1$ and $f(a_2)=b_2$. Then, we have
$$g(a_1, a_2)=(f(a_1), f(a_2))=(b_1, b_2)$$ so the element $(a_1, a_2)$ is mapped to $(b_1, b_2)$ by $g$ so $g$ is surjective.

Now we see that $g$ is a bijection since it is both injective and surjective.